# Unity C# Nested IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code I have nested IEnumerator methods, such like this :

```
    private IEnumerator PerformRequest(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        // Doing stuff
    }

    private IEnumerator PerformRequest2(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        return PerformRequest(url);

        // Doing stuff
    }

    public IEnumerator PerformRequest3(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        return PerformRequest2(url);

        // Doing stuff
    }
```

I am wondering what is the difference if I add `yield` in upper level methods, such like this :

```
    private IEnumerator PerformRequest(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        // Doing stuff
    }

    private IEnumerator PerformRequest2(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        yield return PerformRequest(url);

        // Doing stuff
    }

    public IEnumerator PerformRequest3(string url) {

        // Doing stuff

        yield return PerformRequest2(url);

        // Doing stuff
    }
```

Is there a difference, or is it the same behaviour ?

Thank you !

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd guess that would yield an IEnumerator<IEnumerator<IEnumerator<string>>>, which probably isn't what you want. Can you try adding types to the IEnumerators to check? (which is a good idea anyway)

Comment: yes, this will return IEnumerator of IEnumerators. unless Unity supports it (I don't think it does), it will not work

Comment: In fact if I add the `yield` it returns `IEnumerator<UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation>`, `IEnumerator<IEnumerator<UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation>>`, ect.. 
The code runs without error, but I can't really test if the method really sends the request (I don't the server back-end yet). But is there a difference between `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator<IEnumerator<T>>` ?

Comment: @Adassko This is specific to Unity coroutines. It does work similarly to regular enumerators, but the coroutine has some special magic to it too..

Comment: @Draco18s yes I know about coroutines in Unity. I'm not sure without testing if you can nest coroutines in coroutines though

Comment: @Adassko Sure, see my answer. It doesn't need `IEnumerator<IEnumerator<...>>` either, because the return value from `PerformRequest` is `IEnumerator` which is then *directly returned again* by `PerformRequest2`

Comment: yes, I just read that nested coroutines are supported https://www.alanzucconi.com/2017/02/15/nested-coroutines-in-unity/ I didn't say IEnumerator<IEnumerator<>> is required - this is just what will be happening underneath. The only con of that is that the stacktrace will be longer which means with thousands of nested coroutines in this way we could get stackoverflow exception

Comment: @Adassko I know you didn't, I was merely referencing the other comment.

Comment: I actually created a youtube video showing nested coroutines and how I used them in a game! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szI0NL9-Nbo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Sure, this works

I've done *something like this* myself before, you can absolutely `yield` a method that it itself yeilds, because what happens is that execution is *completely linear* and when `PerformRequest` yields and returns some value (the web request, but not actually important) that propagates up to the `yield return...` in `PerformRequest2` which then propagates upwards to `PerformRequest3`. Unity will resume execuction at the correct location just fine (and you could have answered your own question by testing it, too ;).

Basically its the same as any other nested function, e.g

```
int GetValue() {
    return 4;
}

int GetValue2() {
    return GetValue();
}
```

Is executed exactly the same as (just with a different type):

```
IEnumerator GetValue() {
    return new SomeIEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator GetValue2() {
    return GetValue();
}
```

Which converts to coroutine yielding (`yield` is just a special keyword, it doesn't effect return type!):

```
IEnumerator GetValue() {
    yield return new SomeIEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator GetValue2() {
    yield return GetValue();
}
```

You could also do it like this, but I *generally* don't find any value in it:

```
IEnumerator GetValue() {
    yield return new SomeIEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator GetValue2() {
    //other stuff, with yield so our function still returns a value
    StarCoroutine(GetValue());
    //this stuff runs without waiting
}
```

Adassko also found [this great tutorial](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2017/02/15/nested-coroutines-in-unity/) about coroutines and nested coroutines.

Comment: The last example `StartCoroutine` without `yield` it works different since the upper calling routine `GetValue2` won't be "stalled" until `GetValue` finished.  The difference why sometimes it might be good to use `StartCoroutine` at all is that this way you can also `StopCoroutine` it .. using only `yield return SomeIEnumerator` you cant stop it unless you stop the upper calling routine I guess ...?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, see the comments above and below those lines. However, I see people call start coroutine as the *last* line of an existing coroutine regularly, in which case they are (effectively) the same.

Comment: Maybe .. but not in OP's examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting in Draco18s answer, that this:

```
IEnumerator GetValue() {
    // This line won't work.
    yield return new SomeIEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator GetValue2() {
    //other stuff, with yield so our function still returns a value
    StarCoroutine(GetValue());
    //this stuff runs without waiting
}
```

won't work, cause you need to yield the nested coroutine inside a `StartCoroutine` call,
so it needs to be:

```
IEnumerator GetValue() {
    // The corrected line.
    yield return StartCoroutine(SomeIEnumerator());
}

IEnumerator GetValue2() {
    //other stuff, with yield so our function still returns a value
    StarCoroutine(GetValue());
    //this stuff runs without waiting
}
```

Comment: But .. again you didn't `yield` the `StartCoroutine(GetValue())` .. the other `StartCoroutine` is redundant as you can simply `yield return SomeIEnumerator` directly ...

Comment: @Tenretni No, because I assumed that the `StartCoroutine` was already called was called on `GetValue2` (or on an unshown `GetValue3`) and `SomeIEnumerator` is a standin for `WaitForSeconds` or similar (so that line definitely does work).